# Debian virtual instance gives "No space left on device" during upgrade from wheezy to jessie

Tags: debian, upgrade

I'm half way done and the upgrade process has terminated in the mid. Its about my virtual debian wheezy instance setup under virtualbox that I was upgrading.

Output of df -h is as follows :

```
Filesystem           Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/01a-root ext4      5.0G  4.9G     0 100% /
udev                 devtmpfs   10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                tmpfs     149M  348K  148M   1% /run
tmpfs                tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                tmpfs     297M     0  297M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1            ext4      236M   19M  205M   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/01a-home ext4      5.0G  246M  4.5G   6% /home
/dev/sdb1            ext4       47G  180M   47G   1% /gg/gg01
/dev/sdb2            ext4       47G  180M   47G   1% /gg/gg02
/dev/sdb3            ext4       47G  180M   47G   1% /gg/gg03
/dev/sdb4            ext4       57G  192M   56G   1% /gg/gg04
tmpfs                tmpfs     357M  4.0K  357M   1% /tmp
none                 vboxsf    222M   20M  203M   9% /media/sf_K2
none                 vboxsf    222M   20M  203M   9% /media/sf_k1
none                 vboxsf    346G  189G  158G  55% /media/sf_sh01
none                 vboxsf    346G  189G  158G  55% /media/sf_sh_mcn

  vgdisplay 01a
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               01a
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               29.05 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7437
  Alloc PE / Size       2651 / 10.36 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       4786 / 18.70 GiB
  VG UUID               Vltnqr-dDCv-VnlD-7pts-MYCB-8u7w-QNCHk3
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**Additional Info to the above question after discussion with @Sekenre in the comments below** :

Hello, here is the history in more details :
First of all, this is a virtual drive for this debian instance installed in virtualbox.
Historically, while creating it, I used the following options :

```
*Partitions : /home and the rest
*Using LVM
*Name of Volume Group : 01a
```

Next, some 1.5 years back, I came across the need for more space, and so I pursued the following process :

In the beginning, I only had sda5 physical volume.

I used vboxmanage to increase disk size to 30000 mbs
Next, cfdisk was used to add new physical volume sda6 (lvmspace/ 8e) on the new empty space.
Next, the new sda5 pv was added to the main vg 01a :

```
 vgextend 01a /dev/sda6
```

With that, vg 01a became around 30gb.
Then, the first lv on vg 01a named "root" was extended :

```
lvresize -L 5G /dev/01a/root
```

Next, the filesystem was resized :

```
resize2fs -f -p /dev/01a/root
```

This led us to the current scenario. Right now :

```
>pvscan
PV /dev/sda5   VG 01a   lvm2 [7.76 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sda6   VG 01a   lvm2 [21.29 GiB / 18.70 GiB free]
Total: 2 [29.05 GiB] / in use: 2 [29.05 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

>pvdisplay -m
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda5
VG Name               01a
PV Size               7.76 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              1986
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          1986
PV UUID               txt13Y-x6Rj-KgLM-hpNL-uklw-uJaf-Xx0ET1

--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 614:
Logical volume      /dev/01a/root
Logical extents     0 to 614
Physical extent 615 to 689:
Logical volume      /dev/01a/swap_1
Logical extents     0 to 74
Physical extent 690 to 1985:
Logical volume      /dev/01a/home
Logical extents     0 to 1295

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda6
VG Name               01a
PV Size               21.30 GiB / not usable 3.97 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              5451
Free PE               4786
Allocated PE          665
PV UUID               Z2JwLd-d5Zs-0GGR-hE5P-69eP-9TTD-fF4y01

--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 664:
Logical volume      /dev/01a/root
Logical extents     615 to 1279
Physical extent 665 to 5450:
FREE

>lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/01a/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                01a
LV UUID                qh5Lon-k6eL-ZlOM-3RGv-mMvg-aPLW-1f1TuW
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time D-710-64-01, 2013-06-23 17:16:42 +0530
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                5.00 GiB
Current LE             1280
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/01a/swap_1
LV Name                swap_1
VG Name                01a
LV UUID                2Glp7C-20Mc-H0RT-G0xt-Nqyt-wp3v-6wGz0p
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time D-710-64-01, 2013-06-23 17:16:43 +0530
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                300.00 MiB
Current LE             75
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:1

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/01a/home
LV Name                home
VG Name                01a
LV UUID                l3dh7W-fPkC-Chj2-EXdK-5egB-QUOw-iWz5I6
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time D-710-64-01, 2013-06-23 17:16:43 +0530
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                5.06 GiB
Current LE             1296
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:2
```

================

@Sekenre, I hope your suggestions are in sync with this current configuration. Just wanted to share this with you for your review. Thanks once again friend. Gratitude!

Comment: Your root partition is out of space. Debian downloads all update packages to the `/var` filesystem which on your setup looks like it's in the root partition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sekenre, I'm new to linux os concepts... Can you guide me on this on what I should do next? Want to know if I have to increase root partition's size, which seems an lvm partition. Based on the result of fdisk -l, can you guide me how to and from where I should add more space to root partition? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vishal, could you remove the output of `fdisk -l` from your answer and give us the output of `vgdisplay 01a` This will show me if you can create a new Logical volume, or have the space to expand the root volume.

Comment: OK, working on a full answer for you.

Comment: pv sda6 seems to have unallocated space : Physical extent 665 to 5450:
FREE.

Comment: `/dev/01a/root is 5GiB`
    `/dev/01a/swap_1 300MiB`
    `/dev/01a/home is 5Gib`

I hope we can use the unallocated space on 01a.
Can we directly do the following and add 5 more GiBs to :
    `lvresize -L 10G /dev/01a/root`
    `resize2fs -f -p /dev/01a/root`

... and our problem should be solved? Thanks @Sekenre!

Comment: Hi Vishal, my only concern was making the space available while the system was running, your solution will work fine too. Remember to accept the answer that worked best for you. :)

Comment: Thanks @Sekerne. I did press that tick button to confirm that I went with the answer I myself proposed.. I do thank you for all your valued help, and will revisit your suggestion down the line when once again in similar situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pv sda6 seems to have unallocated space :

```
Physical extent 665 to 5450: FREE
```

And :

```
/dev/01a/root is 5GiB
/dev/01a/swap_1 300MiB
/dev/01a/home is 5Gib
```

I hope we can use the unallocated space on 01a.
Can we directly do the following and add 5 more GiBs to :

```
lvresize -L 10G /dev/01a/root
resize2fs -f -p /dev/01a/root
```

... and our problem should be solved?
/root should become 10G, right? Should I proceed with this?

Comment: Hello @Sekerne, adapted this, and it worked out great... Completed upgrading my system.. thought to update you on this... Many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you create a new Logical volume with sufficient space, mount it to a temporary location, move/copy the contents of the current `/var` directory over, edit your fstab so that `/var/` is mounted in the new location, remove some of the package files from the original `/var` and then reboot.

To begin, create the new var logical volume:

```
lvcreate -L10G --name var 01a
```

Now, create a filesystem on it:

```
mkfs.ext4 -L VAR /dev/mapper/01a-var
```

Mount it in a temporary location:

```
mkdir /tmp/new-var
mount /dev/mapper/01a-var /tmp/new-var
```

Copy the existing files in `/var` to the new location:

```
cd /var
tar -cf - . | (cd /tmp/new-var && tar -xf -)
cd -
```

Make sure this command is successful before you continue!

```
ls /tmp/new-var
# Did everything copy ok?
umount /tmp/new-var
```

Remove some of the apt cache files so you have working space on root:

```
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

Now run the following command to make sure the new logical volume comes up on boot as `/var`:

```
echo "/dev/mapper/01a-var   /var  ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

Now you should be able to reboot and have plenty of space in both root and var!

Edit to add a guide on what all the LVM stuff is about: http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/ubuntu-lvm-guide-part-1.html

Comment: Thanks @Sekerne, I'm trying to understand your directions step by step. But I just wanted to share with you more details about the current setup, and so I did update the above questions with additional info. Thanks.